# I need to take user input and add it to a dictionary but it keeps replacing the previous key and value instead of adding a new one

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Here is the function that I have, and I have the user input split into the variables command, name, and ip_address. I know that those pass correctly because I tested it with the three print statements,, and when I call the function it prints out the right dictionary key and value, but when I run the function again, it replaces the key and value instead of adding a new one. How can I make it add a new key and value instead of replacing the old one?

```
def server_create(command, name, ip_address):
    print(name)
    print(command)
    print(ip_address)+
    server_list = {}
    server_list[name] = ip_address
```

Comment: You set `server_list` to an empty dictionary `{}` every time you invoke the function provided. How is it the behavior you describe is not what you expect from this code?

Comment: Can you share the code where you call `server_create`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, since you set server_list to an empty dictionary each time, that will not work. You would have to do something like this:

```
server_list = {}

def server_create(command, name, ip_address, s_list):
      s_list[name] = ip_address
```

And then call it as:

```
server_create(command, name, ip_address, server_list)
```